# Subtract opencv matrix from 3 channel matrix

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have two matrices:

```
        cv::Mat bgr(rows, cols, CV_16UC3);
        cv::Mat ir(rows, cols, CV_16UC1 );
```

and I want to subtract *ir* from each channel of *bgr* element-wise. I couldn't find an elegant solution yet.

**EDIT**

One possible solution might be:

```
    // subtract IR from BGR
    Vec3u tmp;
    for (int i = 0; i < ir.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ir.cols; j++) {
            tmp = bgr.at<Vec3u>(i,j);
            tmp[0] = tmp[0] - ir.at<ushort>(i,j);
            tmp[1] = tmp[1] - ir.at<ushort>(i,j);
            tmp[2] = tmp[2] - ir.at<ushort>(i,j);

            bgr.at<Vec3u>(i, j) = tmp;
        }
    }
```

The question is that whether there is a faster solution.

Comment: If you ask for elegant ( not optimal ) solution, then a possible way is to convert `ir` to 3 channel matrix in-place and then perform subtraction.

Comment: And what would be an optimal solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we're talking about an elegant way, it could be like this:

```
Mat mat = Mat::ones(2,2,CV_8UC1);
Mat mat1 = Mat::ones(2,2,CV_8UC2)*3;    
Mat mats[2];
split(mat1,mats);
mats[0]-=mat;
mats[1]-=mat;
merge(mats,2,mat1);
```

You shouldn't use  at(), if you wanted your code to be more efficient. Use pointers and check Mats for continuity:

```
int rows = mat.rows;
int cols = mat.cols;

if(mat.isContinuous() && mat1.isContinuous())
{
    cols*=rows;
    rows = 1;
}
for(int j = 0;j<rows;j++) {
    auto channe2limg = mat1.ptr<Vec2b>(j);
    auto channelimg = mat.ptr<uchar>(j);
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
        channe2limg[i][0]-=channelimg[i];
        channe2limg[i][1]-=channelimg[i];          
    }
}
```

Comment: This is faster than `channe2limg.at<Vec2b>(i)[0] -= channelimg.at<uchar>(i);` ?

Comment: channe2limg has a type of  Vec2b*, therefore hasn't  the method at(). If you are asking about whether the version with pointers faster than the version with at(),  then yes, it does, because you obtain an address of a row either only once at all or only once per outer loop iteration, and without checking for the range.